# "ExceptionMessage": "The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'."

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm writing an ASP.NET Web API project with 3 controllers

1. HomeController
2. LaureatesController
3. PrizesController

When I try to call `GET` method `GetPrizes()` from Postman or the web, I'm getting this error

> The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'

My DB and `PrizesController`:

```
private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

public IEnumerable<object> GetPrizes()
{
    var prizes = db.Prizes.ToList()
                   .Select(prize => new
                                    {
                                        prize.PrizeID,
                                        prize.Category,
                                        prize.Year,
                                        Laureates = prize.Laureates.Select(Laureate => new
            {
                Laureate.LaureateID,
                Laureate.Surname,
                Laureate.FirstName,
                Laureate.Gender,
                Laureate.Born,
                Laureate.BornCountry,
                Laureate.Died
            })
        });
            
    return db.Prizes;
}
```

I have added in the `webApiconfig.cs` file:

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }

        );

        var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
        json.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;

}
```

and my `Global.ASAX` contains:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}
```

Do you have any Idea on what is wrong here and I'm getting that error?

Comment: I assume that you call the `GetPrizes` API and get the error mentioned. Can you provide the complete code? What value are you returning in that API as you don't show us the `return` statement?

Comment: have updated my code, is it what you need?

Comment: Yes, it's kind of weird that you return the `db.Prizes`. I expect that you should return the `prizes`, the query result which you fetch from the DB.

Comment: i have changed the code from return db.prizes to return prizes and it works. thank you for the quick resolution.